# remove list Items from ObservableCollection<List> determined by DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, observablecollection

I have an List in my app wich is generated in an MVVM light MainViewModel, the property for it is "Daylist", i also get an _daylist from it, but i want to remove some specific list items that are older then DateTime.Now. lets say like this: the list give me hours like 12:00, 15:00, 18:00 but right now it is 17:00 so i want to remove all entries fro mthe generated list that are older then DateTime.Now.

This is the property i use to get the list:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the DayList property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<List> DayList
    {
        get
        {
            return _dayList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_dayList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(DayListPropertyName);
            _dayList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(DayListPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

I get an list of 29 items, and each item has an DateTime ("Time") wich holds the dates and hours like 21-05-2014 12:00 and so on. i just need an way to return the items list without the items that are already passed.

I just dont know how to acces each item separatelly and check if its value is <= DateTime.Now. Is there an easy way of doing this from within this property i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas the `List<T>` data type would offer you a one-liner `DayList.RemoveAll(x => x.Time < DateTime.Now)`, using `ObservableCollection<T>` requires going through a list:

```
foreach (var item in DayList.Where(x => x.Time < DateTime.Now).ToList())
{
    DayList.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. i just implemented it after the RaisePropertyChanged and i thought also it must go this way but never thought about linq. Thank you. :) Now my list looks better.